# hook form submit being called twice

Tags: forms

In the following code custom call back function is being printed twice. How to prevent submit call back function being called twice.

```
function my_module_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
 if ($form['#id'] == "views-exposed-form-test-page"){
    $form['#submit'][] = 'custom_callback';
  }
}

function custom_callback($form,&$form_state){
    $form_state['redirect'] = false;
    dpm("insert record");
}
```

Comment: is `hook_form_alter()` firing twice resulting in the custom callback firing twice? Or is the `hook_form_alter()` being fired once, and the custom function is firing twice?

Comment: hook_form_alter is firing twice . if  i dpm("test") inside hook form it display twice.

Comment: Can you run `dpm($form_id);` inside your `hook_form_alter(&$form, $form_id)`, do you get different form ID's?

Comment: its giving me same form_id

Comment: Is your form being outputted more than once on the page you are on? How are you rendering the form?

Comment: its view expose filter form. Though it is rendered once only

Answer (score 1):

`hook_form_alter()` will fire once for every time there is a form on the current page.

You can try the hook [`hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7.x). This will only run once when the form with the specific ID pops up.

Unfortunately I had this issue happen before, the `hook_form_alter()` ran multiple times. I stopped the code from running multiple times by encapsulating the code inside an IF statement inside the `hook_form_alter()` example: `if($form_id == my_id)`. So the hook ran multiple times but the code only ran once.